# Hide the div on the condition

Tags: html, css, jsp, jasperserver

I am looking for some inline solution for this problem:

```
<div id="xy<%=statusCount%>" style="margin-top: 50px;display:${<%= statusCount %>!=0 ? 'none' : ''};" class="XYZ">
```

gives me error

<%= statusCount %> is giving me 0 but its not evaluating the condition.

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [${<%= statusCount %>!=0 ? 'none' : ''}]

Answer (score 0):

using templating require backtick `
example:

```
style=`margin-top: 50px; display: ${<%= statusCount %> != 0 ?  'none'  : ''};`
```